# Convert between date formats in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, ios8.1

I am trying to convert a date into a different format. I'm receiving my date as an NSString with the following format: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy`, and am attempting to change it to this format: `dd-mm-yy`. However, I am not able to get it in desired format.

This is my current code:

```
    NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"createdOn"]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = gmt;
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
    NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

Comment: How are you getting the format? dd/mm/yyyy? Maybe try @"dd-MM-yyyy".

Comment: @Rob: I am getting date as string in this format "Tue Mar 24 08:28:48 IST 2015" and i am attempting to change it to "dd-MM-yyyy".

Comment: I am getting dateFromString as nil. after getting nil value no matter what dateFormatter2 outputs which is nothing but nil again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale `en_US` doesn't understand the `IST` time zone abbreviation. But `en_IN` does:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Tue Mar 24 08:28:48 IST 2015";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

As [John Skeet points out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13449004/1271826), the issue probably stems from the fact that `IST` is not unique. IST stands for both [Israel Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-israel), and [India Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist). Thus, when you specify India locale, it makes a reasonable assumption, but for US locale, it is understandably confused.

---

Unrelated, but make sure to use `MM` rather than `mm` in your output formatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```