# Custom date string to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert  `Mon, 01 Aug 2016 04:15 PM IST` to NSDate

I tried using the below code but always stuck with nil. Please help

```
 NSString *fullTime = @"Mon, 01 Aug 2016 04:15 PM IST";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a ZZZ"];
 NSDate *tempTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fullTime];
```

Comment: I've played with it around a bit, looks like Its the "IST" that's problematic. There is already a post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928666/how-to-format-the-date-to-ist

Comment: Your issue is with the `IST` part, this three letter timezone is not supported correctly. Also you want to set a locale in the date formatter since the string  contains language specific date:  `dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];`

Comment: As stated by @PiratM you might want to either strip the `IST` from the date string or see if the date string can be changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928666/how-to-format-the-date-to-ist see this

Comment: See my answer.It works perfectly.

Comment: Vashum try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main issue is the `IST` in the date, `IST` is not a standard and can stand for many [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations):

> IST   Indian Standard Time    UTC+05:30
>
> IST   Irish Standard Time UTC+01
>
> IST   Israel Standard Time    UTC+02

The date formatter will not be able to correctly format the date since it does not know which timezone is meant.

If you can you should have the date changed or remove the `IST` part from the date.

Also you will need to add a locale to the date formatter you it knows in which language is used in the date string.
For english beste use en_US_POSIX:

```
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code.First it gives nil.Then I changed LocaleIdentifier to en_IN because

> IST stands for both Israel Standard Time, and India Standard Time also [it indicates this](http://www.worldtimezone.com/wtz-names/wtz-ist.html)

```
NSString *strDate = @"Mon, 01 Aug 2016 04:15 PM IST";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a zzz"];
dateFormat.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"];
NSDate *dateStr = [dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
NSLog(@"The date is - %@",dateStr);
```

The Printed Result is

```
The date is - 2016-08-01 06:45:00 +0000
```

[Convert between date formats in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212471/convert-between-date-formats-in-objective-c)

Comment: It is  working but the time format is NOT in desirable format. Anyway thanks.